# I get an error "Invalid Column Name" even when all the columns are present in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have created a #table inside a stored procedure using a `select * into` statement. The table is shown fine, but when I start using an `if` statement, it says "Invalid Column Name". Why is this happening, the columns are all available in the table I created.

Can anyone tell me whats the issue ?

I have tried using `select * from #table`, all the columns and its values are present.

I have also tried `update #Table` and change several values. It works fine till here.

Only when I use the `if` statement, its showing the error,

```
UPDATE #SMSB_temp
SET Status = '09'
WHERE RenewStatus = '03'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #SMSB_temp)
BEGIN
    IF Status = '09' AND AvailableBalance > @SMSBRenewalCharges
    BEGIN

    END
END
```

Comment: You can't reference a column name as it is without the table in the `IF`. How does `SQL Server` knows the column `Status` and `Available Balance` is from which table ?. Should be `if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #SMSB_temp WHERE Status = '09' and AvailableBalance > @SMSBRenewalCharges) Begin .... End`

Answer (score 1):

You have to write IF statement like below. Your code is currently not referring to any table in the IF statement. I hope you want to check if there is a row with Status = '09' and AvailableBalance > @SMSBRenewalCharges.

```
DECLARE @Check bit

SET @check = (SELECT TOP 1 1
              FROM #SMSB_temp 
              WHERE Status = '09' AND AvailableBalance > @SMSBRenewalCharges)

IF @check = 1
BEGIN
   ...
END
```

As @squirrel suggested in the comments, you can simply write as below:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1
              FROM #SMSB_temp 
              WHERE Status = '09' AND AvailableBalance > @SMSBRenewalCharges)
BEGIN
 ...
END
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner so I have to ask this. What does the "Select Top 1 1" do ?

Comment: @Trincula no problem. It is just selecting TOP 1 row and I am putting 1 as the return value for the selected top row. It will be assigned to check variable.